# how add style for children block when we focus on link?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

Code:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="text1"><a href="#">test1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="test_block">text1</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="text2"><a href="#">test1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="">text2</div>
</div>
```

how make on css3 that when we focus on link(a:hover) children block `test_block` get css `font-size:18px`?

P.S.: For example, when we hover on link `test1` `font-size` for `text1` will be 18 px and `font-size` for `text2` wiil be `14px`;

When we we hover on link `test2` `font-size` for `text2` will be 18 px and `font-size` for `text1` wiil be `14px`;

Answer (score 1):

Use the adjacent sibling selector, `+`:

```
.text1,
.text2 {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.test1:hover + .text1,
.test2:hover + .text2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```